# Data selection using a button

Tags: python, pandas, radio-button, jupyter-notebook, ipywidgets

I would like to create a button on a Jupyter Notebook in order to replace the if statement used in the following code:

```
from ipywidgets import interact
import ipywidgets as widgets
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from IPython.display import display
import scipy as sci

# I create two dataset
x = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 2000)
y1=np.sin(2*x)
y2=np.sin(4*x)
y3=np.sin(8*x)

f1=np.exp(-x**2)
f2=np.exp(-2*x**2)
f3=np.exp(-3*x**2)

ms=[y1,y2,y3]
mt=[f1,f2,f3]
ms=np.transpose(ms)
mt=np.transpose(mt)
dataset_1=pd.DataFrame(ms)
dataset_2=pd.DataFrame(mt)

control=1 # Selection parameter used in the if condition


# This is the condition that I want to replace by a button
if control==1: 
    data=dataset_1
    data.plot()
    plt.show()

elif control==0:
    data=dataset_2
    data.plot()
    plt.show()
```

Here I created two dataset composed by three sines and gaussians respectively.
I wonder if it is possible to use a radio-button like this:

```
widgets.RadioButtons(
options=['dataset 1', 'dataset 2'],
description='Switching:',
disabled=False
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible you just need to create a simple function with you condition and use interact.

```
from ipywidgets import interact
import ipywidgets as widgets
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from IPython.display import display
import scipy as sci

# I create two dataset
x = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 2000)
y1=np.sin(2*x)
y2=np.sin(4*x)
y3=np.sin(8*x)

f1=np.exp(-x**2)
f2=np.exp(-2*x**2)
f3=np.exp(-3*x**2)

ms=[y1,y2,y3]
mt=[f1,f2,f3]
ms=np.transpose(ms)
mt=np.transpose(mt)
dataset_1=pd.DataFrame(ms)
dataset_2=pd.DataFrame(mt)


def f(Dataset):
    control = Dataset
    if control == 'dataset 1': 
        data=dataset_1
        data.plot()
        plt.show()

    elif control== 'dataset 2':
        data=dataset_2
        data.plot()
        plt.show() 
    return Dataset


interact(f, Dataset = widgets.RadioButtons(
options=['dataset 1', 'dataset 2'],
description='Switching:',
disabled=False))
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is.  Create a new cell with the following code:

```
@interact(control=widgets.RadioButtons(
    options=[1,2],
    description='Dataset'
))
def plot_df(control):
    data = eval('dataset_{}'.format(control))
    data.plot()
```

[image]